# Как отобразить результат html в bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, curl

я пробывал сделать это через curl но он не показывает ответ на html запрос а открывает сам html файл
Есть вариант отобразить результат данного html в bash?
https://www.iphones.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/geoloc1.html

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать и какой должен быть результат? Приведите примеры: какая команда? Что получается? Чего хочется?

Comment: ссылка которую я прикрепил запрашивает местоположение,я нажимаю разрешить и страница выдает широту и долготу,хочется получить широту и долготу в bash это возможно?

Comment: `html запрос` что это???

Comment: копайте в сторону wget

Comment: @KryptonH не будет работать запрос местоположения в баше без браузера

Answer (score 2):

Для определения местоположения по ip-адресу, можно использовать такую команду:

```
curl ipinfo.io
```

Для "не своего" ip команда будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8
```

Если установлен `jq`, можно отфильтровать нужные значения как-то вот так:

```
curl --silent ipinfo.io | jq -r .loc
```